# For given matrices prove that ker$(AB)$ = ker $B$ and im$((AB)^T)$ = im$(B^T).$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

The given matrices are $A, B \in R^{n,n}$ such that
$$\ker A \cap \mathrm{im} B = \{0\}.$$
Prove that
$$\ker(AB) = \ker B\text{ and }\mathrm{im}((AB)^T) = \mathrm{im}(B^T).$$

I proved $\ker(AB) = \ker B$ by proving two containments. If $x \in \ker(B)$, then by kernel definition $Bx = 0$ and hence $ABx = 0$, i.e. $x \in \ker(AB)$. The second contaiment: suppose $x \in \ker(AB)$. Then $ABx = 0$. The vector $Bx$ belongs to both $\operatorname{\text{im}}(B)$ and $\ker(A)$, so from assumptions $Bx = 0$. Hence $x \in \ker(B)$.

Is my proof correct?? And also I don't know how to prove (b). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Questions about "is my proof correct" require that you identify a particular step that you are unsure or unclear about, and explicitly explain why that is the case.

Comment: Ok. Do I use and understand definitions correctly?

Comment: Questions should be in the post, not in the comments. If you are asking about the definitions, then you are not asking about the proof. Note that posts should contain just one question, not multiple questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct. To prove (b), note that for an arbitrary $x\in\mathbb R^n$ it holds
$$(AB)^Tx=B^TA^Tx=B^T(A^Tx),$$
hence $\text{im}((AB)^T)\subseteq\text{im}(B^T)$.
Then it is sufficient to check that $\text{dim}_{\mathbb R}\text{im}((AB)^T)=\text{dim}_{\mathbb R}\text{im}(B^T),$
but this follows from the equations
$$\text{dim}_{\mathbb R}\text{im}((AB)^T)+\text{dim}_{\mathbb R}\text{ker}((AB)^T)=n^2,$$
$$\text{dim}_{\mathbb R}\text{im}(B^T)+\text{dim}_{\mathbb R}\text{ker}(B^T)=n^2,$$
using the fact
$$\text{dim}_{\mathbb R}\text{ker}(B^T)=\text{dim}_{\mathbb R}\text{ker}(B)=\text{dim}_{\mathbb R}\text{ker}(AB)=\text{dim}_{\mathbb R}\text{ker}((AB)^T).$$

Comment: So if I prove that $\text{im}((AB)^T)\subseteq\text{im}(B^T)$ and $\text{dim}_{\mathbb R}\text{im}((AB)^T)=\text{dim}_{\mathbb R}\text{im}(B^T)$, then I prove $\mathrm{im}((AB)^T) = \mathrm{im}(B^T)$? It is very interesting, thank you!

Comment: Yes, because in this sense you are considering both $\text{im}((AB)^T)$ and $\text{im}(B^T)$ as $\mathbb R$-vector spaces. Then, since one is contained in another having equal $\mathbb R$-dimension, it forces both to be the same one.

Comment: The answer completes OP's question. I suspect from a cooperation here...

Comment: @BobDobbs Can you specify what you are referring to?

Comment: @Deif It is nice when part a is used in part b. That's all.